# How to write a FAST API function taking .csv file and making some preprocessing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, request, fastapi

I am trying to create an API function, that takes in .csv file (uploaded) and opens it as pandas DataFrame. Like that:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import UploadFile, Query, Form
import pandas as pd

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/check")
def foo(file: UploadFile):
    df = pd.read_csv(file.file)
    return len(df)
```

Then, I am invoking my API:

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/check'
file = {'file': open('data/ny_pollution_events.csv', 'rb')}

resp = requests.post(url=url, files=file)
print(resp.json())
```

But I got such error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ny_pollution_events.csv'`

As far as I understand from [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) pandas is able to read .csv file from file-like object, which `file.file` is supposed to be. But it seems, that here in read_csv() method pandas obtains name (not a file object itself) and tries to find it locally.

Am I doing something wrong?
Can I somehow implement this logic?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't your requests code complaining about `ny_pollution_events.csv` not being present in the directory you're running your client code from? Since there is no reason the server side should attempt to use the file name at all (`file.file` is a file-like object, so there is no file name involved)

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, I am sure. If the problem was in absence of file in the directory I am running my client code from, the error would be like that:  ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/ny_pollution_events.csv'```

Comment: Good point; have you attached a debugger to your view endpoint with a breakpoint at the `read_csv` call to see what the value of `file.file` i?

Comment: @MatsLindh Here is what stored in file.file ```<tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile object at 0x7fabe65bff40>```

Comment: What is the stack trace for where the exception gets raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the file in pandas, the file must be stored on your PC. Don't forget to import `shutil`. if you don't need the file to be stored on your PC, delete it using `os.remove(filepath)`.

```
        if not file.filename.lower().endswith(('.csv',".xlsx",".xls")):
            return 404,"Please upload xlsx,csv or xls file."

        if file.filename.lower().endswith(".csv"):
            extension = ".csv"
        elif file.filename.lower().endswith(".xlsx"):
            extension = ".xlsx"
        elif file.filename.lower().endswith(".xls"):
            extension = ".xls"

        # eventid = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m-%d%H-%M%S-') + str(uuid4())
        filepath = "location where you want to store file"+ extension

        with open(filepath, "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
        
        try:
            if filepath.endswith(".csv"):
                df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
            else:
                df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
        except:
            return 401, "File is not proper"
```